# Botão do AlertDialog não aparece

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer com que o botão <kbd>ok</kbd> apareça.

Quero fazer com `AlertDialog`.

Esse trecho está dentro de uma segunda `Trhead`. Me ajuda?

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
//                                        builder.setMessage("Teste ok?")
//                                                .setTitle("TESTE OK?");
//                                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // User clicked OK button
                                        startActivity(new   Intent(CadastroActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                                 dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: ta faltando você colocar ai dialog.show() depois do create();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ficara assim:*

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    //                                        builder.setMessage("Teste ok?")
    //                                                .setTitle("TESTE OK?");
    //                                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            // User clicked OK button
                                            startActivity(new   Intent(CadastroActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                                     dialog = builder.create();
                                     dialog= builder.show();
```

Comment: huehuehuehue esqueci do show();